# How to go Internet Settings in Android using code

Tags: android, android-settings

I am using Webview to display some webpage , I wanted to know how to go Android Internet Setting when there is no Internet. I have provided a Button and when the user clicks on it , It should go to settings , Can it be done? if that is so Please tell me how to do this. 
Thanks .

This is the code I am using

```
       settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
                reload.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Sportee.this.webView.loadUrl("http://blah.blah.com");
            } else {
                reload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               //Here I have to write code to go for settings 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Going to Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Function to check whether Internet is available or what

```
   private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you google before posting questions here. There are many answers out there for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the settings page programmatically by using the following method:

```
startActivity(new Intent(
    Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));  //Or ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS
```

Check out the full list of intent data you can use [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

Comment: sir it needs Bluetooth permission also

Comment: And that is why i provided the link so you can search for exactly which page you want to open in the settings and open it.
Anyways here is the constant you are looking for ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

You can open different settings by checking the constants in [Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)